# Where is servlet-api.jar in Glassfish 5.1?

Tags: servlets, glassfish, application-server

Trying to build a Java web-site, i'm getting errors:

[image]

> The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved

Some searching implies that in order to import `javax.servlet` you need a special jar file that comes with your <strike>web-server</strike> application server:

- `servlet-api.jar`<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119448/the-import-javax-servlet-cant-be-resolved) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196936/why-does-import-javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved-despite-of-installing-java-e) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456446/javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-jakarta-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143145/the-import-javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved-still) [6](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2424787-the-import-javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved) [7](https://tech.amikelive.com/node-269/eclipse-quick-tip-resolving-error-the-import-javaxservlet-cannot-be-resolved/) [8](https://intellipaat.com/community/70956/the-import-javax-servlet-cant-be-resolved) [9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4PZgXF3Pso) [10](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/solved-httpservlet-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) [11](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/200) [12](https://yazilimcity.net/the-import-javax-servlet-servletexception-cannot-be-resolved/) [13](https://www.reddit.com/r/eclipse/comments/mldp8w/how_to_fix_import_javaxservlet_cannot_be_resolved/) [14](https://www.buggybread.com/2013/01/import-javaxservlet-cant-be-resolved.html?m=0) [15](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4119448/) [16](https://stdworkflow.com/1275/eclipse-import-project-error-the-import-javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved) [17](https://blog.katastros.com/a?ID=00900-5cf3f4c4-98d9-4901-bb65-446fa5c7fb08) [18](https://crunchify.com/how-to-resolve-exception-httpservlet-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/) [19](https://eeengineer.com/java-how-to-solve-the-import-javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved-error/) [20](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1677959/the-import-javax-servlet-cannot-be-resolved-what-do-i-wrong) [21](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/exception-handling/solved-the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build-path-in-eclipse/) [22](https://atoz-develop.tistory.com/entry/The-import-javaxservlet-cannot-be-resolved-%EC%97%90%EB%9F%AC-%ED%95%B4%EA%B2%B0-%EB%B0%A9%EB%B2%95) [23](https://www.javafixing.com/2022/03/fixed-import-javaxservlet-cannot-be.html) [24](https://blog.karthisoftek.com/a?ID=00700-551679d3-ac92-4423-9217-58fcece6e7cb)</sup>

I did a search of the files in the installation folder of Glassfish 5.1. There is no `servlet-api.jar`. I so searched for any filenames that contain the words <kbd>javax</kbd> or <kbd>servlet</kbd>:

```
C:\Users\ian\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\modules

06/29/2022  11:37 AM            34,641 javax.batch-api.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM            95,067 jakarta.servlet-api.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM            66,437 jakarta.servlet.jsp-api.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM           561,358 jakarta.servlet.jsp.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM            56,706 jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM         3,689,362 jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM            26,966 jersey-cdi1x-servlet.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM            73,338 jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM            32,135 jersey-container-servlet.jar
06/29/2022  11:37 AM            26,189 tyrus-container-servlet.jar
```

Which one of these files represents `javax.servlet`, and how would I know?

I did a grep of all the files in the folder, and none contain the ASCII text "javax.servlet".

### Research Effort

- [where is the servlet-api.jar in glassfish installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572667/where-is-the-servlet-api-jar-in-glassfish-installation)
- [Where do I get servlet-api.jar from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521851/where-do-i-get-servlet-api-jar-from)
- [Can't reference servlet-api.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467723/cant-reference-servlet-api-jar)
- [Java compile error. servlet-api.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347157/java-compile-error-servlet-api-jar)
- [Difference between javax.servlet-api.jar vs servlet-api.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349047/difference-between-javax-servlet-api-jar-vs-servlet-api-jar)
- [why do we set path for Servlet-api.jar only. What about Jsp-api.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229440/why-do-we-set-path-for-servlet-api-jar-only-what-about-jsp-api-jar)
- [servlet-api.jar cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244964/servlet-api-jar-cannot-be-loaded)

Comment: You missed jakarta.servlet-api.jar?

Comment: @BalusC I certainly didn't miss `jakarta.servlet-api.jar`. I specifically included it in the above list.

Comment: It is in there.

Comment: How did you know that? How do i know that? How do we know that? How is that known?

Comment: The file name matches the expected artifact id of Servlet 4.x https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/4.0.2

Comment: But....what about https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api

Comment: That's for among others GlassFish 5.0 which is the last Oracle-maintained Java EE version. You've a 5.1 which is the first Eclipse-maintained Jakarta EE version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you're looking for "jakarta.servlet-api.jar" in GlassFish 5.1.

"servlet-api.jar" is the old name of the artefact. Artefacts get renamed from time to time. Specifically after Java EE moved to the Eclipse foundation to become Jakarta EE, quite a few things got renamed.

You could have known by not looking for the jar name, but for which jars contain the actually classes you're looking for (e.g. use unzip -l recursively on all jar files in /modules and grep on that).

For some background on the move from Oracle to Eclipse, see https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee